# Chamar 2 eventos no onclick

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics-api

estou desenvolvendo um site, e preciso acionar 2 eventos quando um texto é clicado.
Uma função js, e um código de acompanhamento de metas do google analytics.
Segue exemplo

```js
function shownumber() {
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = "<small>(62)</small> 9999-9999";
}
```

```html
<p class="fixed__box__number" id="number">
    <small>(62)</small> 9999-99...
    <span onclick="shownumber();ga('send', 'event', 'Telefone', 'Clicar');">ver telefone</span>
</p>
```

Como estou fazendo no localhost não consigo testar se os 2 estão funcionando. E creio não estar, pois alterei a ordem da call para a função e não ativou a função, portanto, o código que mandei aqui não está funcionando.

Como seria feito para adicionar 2 eventos no onclick com JavaScript nativo? Existe outra forma de fazer isso mais fácil/certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer isso de duas maneiras:

Usa `(A(), B(), C())` para invocar várias ações:

```
onclick="(foo('html'), bar('html'))"
```

ou faz tudo no JavaScript:

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    foo('addEventListener');
    bar('addEventListener');
});
```

Um exmeplo com ambas as versões em baixo:

```js
function foo(quem) {
    console.log('foo', quem);
}

function bar(quem) {
    console.log('bar', quem);
}

var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    foo('addEventListener');
    bar('addEventListener');
});
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="(foo('html'), bar('html'))">Clica-me</button>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dheqgokq/

Comment: Irmão, sou bem iniciante em javascript, e não saquei muito esse codígo. Tem alguma solução mais explicativa ou com o meu problema aplicado, de fato?